# Why are so many questions that were rewarded the reversal badge deleted?

Tags: discussion, badges

I was just checking out the [Reversal Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) page.  The badge has only been awarded 186 times.

I noticed that many of the questions that received this badge now say `(post deleted or otherwise unavailable)` .

I counted 21 of these out of 60 questions on page 1. Why is that?

Comment: Probably because questions that reach a -5 score tend to be more likely to be deleted

Comment: So they were deleted by moderators? Isn't there potentially some value in the answers? I'd be annoyed if I got this badge and then my answer was deleted.

Comment: It seems like the deleted questions are mostly those with answers of little to no value. The answer to [this deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376339/body-has-already-been-defined-for-function-main/12376362#12376362), for example, read (in full): "You have 2 main functions there can only be one." It has 52 upvotes, but it's arguably hardly worth preserving. Neither is the question, which is just a wall of code

Comment: @Pekka웃 **>_<**

Comment: Ok...cool interesting!

Comment: How does that happen?  Must have been his username.

Comment: @Dan: avoid frustration by not answering awful questions. As a bonus, you'll also avoid teaching people who ask horrible questions that they'll get good answers and should keep on doing it.

Comment: I don't get what the condition for the "(post deleted or otherwise unavailable)" message are. There are some questions which are deleted but still listed with links. For example "What is your most used .NET namespace?" has been deleted in 2012 but is still clickable.